# Fuzzy String match and merge database - Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join, match, fuzzy-comparison

I have two dataframes (with strings) that I am trying to compare to each other. One has a list of areas, the other has a list of areas with long,lat info as well. I am struggling to write a code to perform the following:

1) Check if the string in df1 matches (or a partially matches) area names in df2, then it will merge & carry over the long lat columns.

2) if df1 does not match with df2, then the new column will have NaN or zero.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('Dubai Communities1.csv')
df1.head()

    CNAME_E1
0   Abu Hail
1   Al Asbaq
2   Al Aweer First
3   Al Aweer Second
4   Al Bada 

df2 = pd.read_csv('Dubai Communities2.csv')
df2.head()

    COMM_NUM    CNAME_E2    Latitude    Longitude
0   315         UMM HURAIR  55.3237     25.2364
1   917         AL MARMOOM  55.4518     24.9756
2   624         WARSAN      55.4034     25.1424
3   123         AL MUTEENA  55.3228     25.2739
4   813         AL ROWAIYAH 55.3981     25.1053
```

The output after search and join will look like this:

```
    CName_E1    CName_E3    Latitude    Longitude
0   Area1       Area1       22          7.25
1   Area2       Area2       38          71.83
2   Area3       NaN         NaN         NaN
3   Area4       Area4       35          8.05
```